# Possible reasons and solutions for Google Fit Error 19

Tags: android, google-fit

A user of [Soccer Referee Pro watchface](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pipperpublishing.soccerrefpro) reported an error I haven't seen before: *Error 19 when the watch tries to connect to Google Fit.* According to the docs, I think this is `SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION` for some aspect of Google Play Services.

Here are the APIs I am connecting to:

```
.addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)  //records low power information
.addApiIfAvailable(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
.addApiIfAvailable(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
.addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
```

According to the docs, `startResolutionForResult` is not available from a Watchface service.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I guess you have fixed your error in this thread: https://plus.google.com/114088016527798494004/posts/RP4f4i6qBDx

Comment: Well I don't have confirmation from my user yet, but this is what I surmise: "Ok, a quick test seems to track down the error. I can successfully use my watch in fitness mode WITHOUT Google Fit itself having Sensors or Location permissions granted (presumably because I use the Google Fit API but call Sensors and Location stuff from my watchface). But if I disable SENSORS permission in Google Play Services I get the Error 19. I'll see if this is my user's problem/solution."

Answer (score 1):

The user has confirmed that re-enabling Sensors permission for Google Play Services fixed the problem. I don't really understand why Sensors permission is included in Google Play Services permissions (and this model may have changed in 10.x of Google Play Services), but there you go. i should indeed be checking for this error code and using startResolutionForResult via a call out to an app.